# Upper bound on symbol set's cardinality

Tags: expectation, information-theory

Let's consider a symbol source that generates symbols as following:

> Fix a distribution for the symbols' lengths $P_L$ over $\mathbb{N}$
>   with finite mean $E(L)$. Generate $A$ independently and identically
>   distributed (i.i.d.) random variables $L_1,L_2,...,L_A$ from $P_L$. We
>   next generate a sequence of binary strings $X_a\in\{0,1\}^{L_a}$ for
>   each $a\in\{1,2,...,A\}$. Starting with $a = 1$, choose $X_a$
>   uniformly at random from
>   $\{0,1\}^{L_a}\setminus\{X_1,X_2,...,X_{a-1}\}$. Thus, each $X_a$ is a
>   binary string of length $L_a$, called a source symbol. The source
>   alphabet $\mathcal{X}\subset\{0,1\}^*$ (where $\{0,1\}^*$ denotes the
>   set of all finite-length binary sequences) is defined as the union of
>   all the source symbols $$\mathcal{X}\triangleq\{X_a\}_{a=1}^A$$

Note that $|\mathcal{X}|=A$ by construction. The author first assumes that $L$ is tightly concentrated around its mean, specifically that $P(E(L)/2\leq L\leq 2E(L))
= 1$. Furthermore, to ensure that the source alphabet generation is always well defined, he assumes that $2\leq A\leq 2^{E(L)/2-1}$.

What I don't understand is why the number of symbols is upper bounded by $2^{E(L)/2-1}$. This doesn't seem obvious from Markov or Kraft inequality. The paper is [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.04451).